# split dataframe into two or more parts

Tags: pandas

I want to create separate data frames where the difference between 2 consecutive rows is not exactly 60.

From the sample data, there should be 2 dataframes (with 3 rows each)

```
from StringIO import StringIO

myst="""905034, 'A', 'some value'
905094, 'B', 'some other value'
905154, 'C', 'some value other'
43, 'x', 'some'
103, 'y', 'value'
163, 'z', 'some value'
"""
u_cols=['column1', 'column2', 'column3']

myf = StringIO(myst)
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(myst), sep=',', names = u_cols)
```

Is there any way to split a dataframe into multiple parts based on a function or criterion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual pattern is a compare-cumsum-groupby, something like

```
>>> grouped = df.groupby((df.column1.diff() != 60).cumsum())
>>> for i, group in grouped:
...     print("group #:", i)
...     print(group)
...     
group #: 1
   column1 column2              column3
0   905034     'A'         'some value'
1   905094     'B'   'some other value'
2   905154     'C'   'some value other'
group #: 2
   column1 column2        column3
3       43     'x'         'some'
4      103     'y'        'value'
5      163     'z'   'some value'
```

---

This works because the comparison gives a True every time a new group begins:

```
>>> df.column1.diff() != 60
0     True
1    False
2    False
3     True
4    False
5    False
Name: column1, dtype: bool
```

And then the cumulative sum of that gives a group id number we can pass as an argument to `groupby`:

```
>>> (df.column1.diff() != 60).cumsum()
0    1
1    1
2    1
3    2
4    2
5    2
Name: column1, dtype: int32
```

Comment: This is machine generated data. There are times when it prints 59 or 61 seconds. Those should be considered as 60. I am getting too many dataframes if I insist on 60 seconds interval. Is there any way to solve this ?

Comment: @shantanuo: you asked for "where the difference between 2 consecutive rows is not exactly 60".  You can change the condition `df.column1.diff() != 60` to anything else you want, of course.

Comment: Yes. But when I rechecked the actual data, I found a few entries of 59. So I got a few dataframes of single records. I tried ... # df.column1.diff() not in [59,60,61] # but that did not work.

Comment: You'd write that version as `~df.column1.diff().isin([59, 60, 61])`.

Comment: There is no method isnotin([59, 60, 61]) nor not_between(59, 61)